# Issues with php require and file path

Tags: php, html, css, path, require

I have a website using php, html and css. Since some of the content will be repeated numerous times on the pages, I have created a seperate file which contains the code that's being repeated. I am then refering to this file from all the pages I need by using

```
require('page.html')
```

The problem now is that I have pages in folders and subfolders, and if I refer to the pages like above, it wont show the content since it can't find "page.html" anymore. I fixed this by changing it to:

```
require('../page.html')
```

However that ain't enough since a lot of the content on "page.html" now uses paths that doesn't work anymore like images. Is there a better way to do this? Or will I have to live with a single folder containing 50 files to avoid dubplicated code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

simply use a `set_include_path` (https://www.php.net/set_include_path) at the beginning of your script and set the path to the directory where your including file exists.

Example: You use the `index.php` as the entry point for the application and it is located in `/var/www/yoursite/web`, your files you want to (e.g. `page.html`) include exists in `/var/www/yoursite/lib`, then simply add the following to your `index.php`:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__) . '../lib/');
```

In your file you want to include the `page.html` you have to execute:

```
include('page.html');
```

That's it :)

Comment: Hmm will this also fix the issues with the images and other references than include/require?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean with images - it does not make any sense to include an image resource in php with `include`

Comment: I mean that when I include a file from another directory, it then loads the page but it does not load the images since they still got the same paths that they have to have to load images on the pages that are not in any folders.

Comment: You should use only one entry point file, like a index.php and pass parameters for dynamically loaded files/content to it, like index.php?site=imprint - similar as described here: http://inobscuro.com/tutorials/read/16/